# How can i autofill with v-text-field

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I am making a form where I need one of the fields to autofill with the other fields for example:

```
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
                  <v-text-field label="code" required  v-model='meeting.code'></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
                  <v-text-field label="password" required v-model='meeting.password'></v-text-field>
                </v-col>                                                                           
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
                  <v-text-field label="Url" required v-model="url"></v-text-field>
                </v-col> 
                 url=https://meeting.com/+"this.meeting.code"+/+"this.meeting.password"+
```

I need the code and password variables to be part of the link in this

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve this? What doesn't work about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a computed property for that:

```js
computed: {
  url() {
    const { code, password } = this.meeting
    return `https://meeting.com/${code}/${password}`
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i put the function in v-text-field component?

Comment: You don't put it in that component. Are you using Single File Components? Then put this computed property in the component that includes all the `v-text-field`s. If you're still unsure I think you can check the documentation on computed properties: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html